# Need help in Calcuated column formula

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

Following is requirement/raw query for calculated column

```
If((POD1 = “Yes” and POD1Status = “Submitted”) OR  (POD2 = “Yes” and POD2Status = “Submitted”) or 
(POD3 = “Yes” and POD3Status = “Submitted”) OR (POD4 = “Yes” and POD4Status = “Submitted”)), (## TRUE Condition##)”Submitted”,
(###FALSE Condition###) 
If(If((POD1 = “Yes” and POD1Status = “In Progress”) or  (POD2 = “Yes” and POD2Status = “In Progress”) or 
(POD3 = “Yes” and POD3Status = “In Progress”) or (POD4 = “Yes” and POD4Status = “In Progress”)), (## TRUE Condition##)” In Progress”, (###FALSE Condition###)”Closed”))
```

Following formula i have tried but it is returns wrong value "**#Name?**". It should be "Submitted" or "In Progress" or "Closed"

```
=IF(OR([Belgium]=TRUE,[Denmark]=TRUE,[Finland]=TRUE,[Ireland]=TRUE,[Italy]=TRUE,[Netherlands]=TRUE,[Spain]=TRUE,[Sweden]=TRUE,[Switzerland]=TRUE,[Andorra]=TRUE,[Greenland]=TRUE,[Iceland]=TRUE,[Liechtenstein]=TRUE,[Luxembourg]=TRUE,[Monaco]=TRUE,[Austria]=TRUE,[Norway]=TRUE,[Portugal]=TRUE),IF(OR(AND([POD 1]="Yes",[POD1Status]="Submitted"),AND([POD 2]="Yes",[POD2Status]="Submitted"),AND([POD 4]="Yes",[POD4Status]="Submitted"),AND([POD 5]="Yes",[POD5Status]="Submitted")),"Submitted",IF(OR(AND([POD 1]="Yes",[POD1Status]="In Progress"),AND([POD 2]="Yes",[POD2Status]="In Progress"),AND([POD 4]="Yes",[POD4Status]="In Progress"),AND([POD 5]="Yes",[POD5Status]="In Progress")),"In Progress","Closed")),"NA")
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved, following formula works for me.

```
=IF(OR([Belgium]=TRUE,[Denmark]=TRUE,[Finland]=TRUE,[Ireland]=TRUE,[Italy]=TRUE,[Netherlands]=TRUE,[Spain]=TRUE,[Sweden]=TRUE,[Switzerland]=TRUE,[Andorra]=TRUE,[Greenland]=TRUE,[Iceland]=TRUE,[Liechtenstein]=TRUE,[Luxembourg]=TRUE,[Monaco]=TRUE,[Austria]=TRUE,[Norway]=TRUE,[Portugal]=TRUE),IF(OR(AND([POD 4]="Yes",[POD4Status]="Submitted"), AND([POD 5]="Yes",[POD5Status]="Submitted"), AND([POD 1]="Yes",[POD1Status]="Submitted"), AND([POD 2]="Yes",[POD2Status]="Submitted")),"Submitted",IF(OR(AND([POD 4]="Yes",[POD4Status]="In Progress"), AND([POD 5]="Yes",[POD5Status]="In Progress"), AND([POD 1]="Yes",[POD1Status]="In Progress"), AND([POD 2]="Yes",[POD2Status]="In Progress")),"In Progress","Closed")),"NA")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying it, one conditional at a time, and work up from there. Eventually you'll find your problem statement.

Comment: It worked? Excellent! Please mark this item as answered if it's all set

Answer (score 0):

What I would do would be to recreate/ export this list to Excel and try to replicate the scenario there first. SharePoint formulas work just fine in Excel, it will allow you to check the formula step by step. I hope this helps.